# How to get CMake executable name in C++ preprocessor definition

Tags: c++, cmake

I have two executable definitions in my CMake file

```
add_executable(ProjectFoo ...)
add_executable(ProjectFoo_UnitTests ...)
```

Is there any way to get name of the executable(either ProjectFoo or ProjectFoo_UnitTests) in C++ code like below? Syntax might not be correct but I hope it clarifies the intention.

```
#if executable_name == ProjectFoo
...
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. the executable is not running at compile time.

Comment: I meant the name of executable

Comment: That does not clarify sergejs doubt.

Comment: If I correctly understand the question, intention is to have a macro or macro-line expression, which can be used in the code and which is evaluated to the name of the executable, into which given code is compiled. Am I right?

Comment: @Tsyvarev that's correct

Comment: I cannot align "currently running" and "at compile time" either. They do not go into one and the same point of time.

Comment: Please provide an example of code which uses the desired construct, just to demonstrate the background/goal of the question.

Comment: @Yunnosch I want to be able to get the name(either ProjectFoo or ProjectFoo_UnitTests) in C++. Clear?

Comment: @OnurA.: Then you probably need to reformulate the question post, so it can be easily understood. Combination of "executable currently running" and "compile time" is very confusing.

Comment: @Tsyvarev my bad. updated the question, hope it clarifies now.

Comment: Yes, the question becomes much better now.

Comment: The example code, is it C++ or Preprocessor directives?

Comment: @sergej Preprocessor directive but I am fine with both options

Comment: Why do you need the name?

Comment: I have some mock headers for testing purposes, so if test configuration is being run, I want to include those mock headers

Comment: If you need to decide whether to include headers or not then the check has to at compile time not run time.

Comment: Yes, then preprocessor check would be better. Thanks!

Comment: Btw: the preprocessor '==' operator doesn't work with strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to know at run time if the running executable is a unit test configuration, pass a dedicated preprocessor definition to your unit test executable:

```
target_compile_definitions(ProjectFoo_UnitTests IS_UNIT_TEST)
```

And check this definition in you C++ code:

```
#if defined (IS_UNIT_TEST)
# include "some_mock.hpp"
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

You may "ship" every your executable with its own macro definition. In that macro you may store the name of the executable:

```
target_compile_definitions(ProjectFoo executable_name=ProjectFoo)
target_compile_definitions(ProjectFoo_UnitTests executable_name=ProjectFoo_UnitTests)
```

Inside the code `executable_name` may be used for extract executable's name:

```
#if executable_name==ProjectFoo
```